# Superposition principle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When we have a differential equation and we apply the superposition principle we split the initial differential equation into sunbproblems.

Suppose we have the differential equation $$L(y)=F$$ applying the superposition principle we have to solve the subproblems $$L(y)=F_1, \ \dots , \ L(y)=F_n$$ where $F=F_1+\dots +F_n$.

Does it stand that the initial equation has a solution **if and only if** the subproblems have solutions?

Or is it just **if**?

Knowing that the each subproblem $L(y)=F_j$ has a solution $y_j$ we have that $y=\sum_{j=0}^n y_j$ is a solution of the initial differential equation $$L(y_1+\dots +y_n)=F_1+\dots +F_n=F$$

Does the other direction also stand?

Knowing that the initial differential equation has a solution, do the subproblems also have a solution?

Comment: Assuming that $F_i$ and $F$ are "good enough" functions and that by $L(y)$ you mean a linear differential operator, the answer is basically "yes". That's just because solution to problem $L(y) = f(x)$ exists no matter what $f$ exactly is if it is "good enough".

Comment: What do you mean by "good enough" ? Yes by $L(y)$ I mean a linear differential operator. @Evgeny

Comment: If you are finding particular solution using Lagrange method, everything boils down to solving system of equations ala $C'(x) = W^{-1}(x) \tilde{f(x)}$, where $C'(x)$ is some vector of parameters, $W(x)$ is a fundamental matrix and $\tilde{f(x)} = (0, 0, \dots, f(x))$. Entries of $W(x)$ are at least $C^r$, so it's good for $f(x)$ at least to be integrable.

Comment: When we are finding the particular solution usin the Method of Undetermined Coefficients? What do we do then? @Evgeny

Comment: I'm not sure that I've understood your question. Could you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: You described what happens when we find the particular solution using Lagrange method, or have I understood it wrong? @Evgeny

Comment: Yes, I used Lagrange method (or method of constant variation -- another name for the same method).

Comment: I haven't understood, when we know that the initial differential equation has a solution, how we conclude that then the subproblems have also a solution... @Evgeny

Comment: Are there any rule that you use to split $F$ into the sum of $F_i$'s ? Because it seems that sometimes you can split a nice $F$ it into something awful and non-integrable, which won't have a nice solution.

Comment: $F$ is a sum of functions, it is either of the form $\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i e^{\beta_i x}$ or $\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i x^i$ or $\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i x^{c_i } e^{\beta_i x}$. So the $F_i$ is either the function $e^{\beta_i x}$ or $x^i$ or $x^{c_i } e^{\beta_i x}$. @Evgeny

Comment: Well, these $F$ and $F_i$ are good enough and solutions to equations with such non-homogeneities surely exist. But in my opinion it's somewhat strange to say that solution to $L(y) = F$ exists because solution to all $L(y) = F_i$ exist and we add them up: solution to $L(y) = F$ exists because $F$ itself is a good function (and vice versa).

Comment: But can we prove that $$\exists \ \text{ solution to } L(y)=F \ \iff \ \exists \ \text{ solutions to } L(y)=F_i$$ ? @Evgeny

Comment: Yes, we can. But, again, $\Leftarrow$ part is trivial and proof  of  $\Rightarrow$ part might involve no information about $F$.

Comment: What do you mean that the proof of $\Rightarrow$ part might involve no information about $F$ ? I got stuck right now... @Evgeny

Comment: Okay. How do you prove that $L(y) = G$ has solutions?

Comment: At each of the above rings I looked if there is a solution for the homogeneous equation and if there is a particular solution for $L(y)=G$. @Evgeny Or do you mean something else?

Comment: No. What proofs for existence of solution of $L(y) = G$ do you know? I'm trying to illustrate that part $\Rightarrow$ is quite nonsensical to me. The fact that $L(y) = F_i$ has solution almost doesn't depend on whether exists solution to $L(y)=F$ or not.

Comment: We can prove the existence using continuity and Lipschitz continuity, can't we? @Evgeny

Comment: Or isn't this correct? @Evgeny

Comment: This is correct. $L(y) = F_i$ has solutions because $F_i$ is nice. But in your case $F_i$ is nice just because it is nice, and not because there is some function $F$ to which $F_i$ add up. And I ran out of words trying to explain why proving $\Rightarrow$ is nonsensical.